# How To Qt Creator Embedded use PSQL

Tags: qt, embedded, device, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to use connection to postgres with Qt Creator for embedded device with the Raspberry Pi 3, however the driver is not loaded. The same application on the desktop is ok.

My example is quite simple.

I have a console project with a main class and in it a log with

```
QSqlDatabase::drivers();
```

In raspberry list only QSQLITE, and desktop list QSQLITE, QPSQL, QMYSQL among others.

I am using oQt Creator Enterprise, connecting to the device with Boot2Qt, that comes with Qt Creator, compilation and execution is everything correctly, however is not listed PSQL driver in device.

Answer (score 0):

QSqlDatabase::drivers() lists only the drivers that can be loaded on that particular platform, in many cases to have a working driver you need the Qt driver and a specific client library.

Probably there is a postgresql client library for raspberry with your specific linux version somewhere but Boot2Qt does not load it automatically to your board.

You have to find the client library for your specific version of linux (maybe you will have to compile it) then manually copy the postgresql Qt driver onto the board and the QSqlDatabase::drivers() should show you the postgresql driver available.

Comment: Thank you Marco, got it.

 I found the library to "arm" libqsqlpsql.so, I copied it to the /usr/lib but without success.

Do you have to somehow register this library?

Comment: No I think it's more complicated, the Qt driver is shipped binary for the major platforms for minor platforms it must be compiled, to compile it you need the development version of the postgresql client and then you have to compile the driver for the specific platform, it can be quite complicated.. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql

Comment: cd $QTDIR/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql
qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/pgsql" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib -lpq" psql.pro
make   these are the generic command to build the driver for the platform where you are working in that moment, but I ma not sure how to do it for another platform